# Webistrano bash/sh problem!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, webistrano

I love Capistrano and finally i found GUI for using it!

**Webistrano!**

I installed the app that many other guys recommend it to me.

Finally, its time to try... I flow the screencast ..etc.. and found in my production.log this error: 'sh: ruby command not found'

I followed this [blog post](http://rubyglasses.blogspot.com/2009/12/getting-webistrano-to-deploy-under.html#webistrano_monkeypatch) but naaaah!! same problem...

This is what i tried in script/console as the blog post said!

```
>> system("sh -c \"ruby -v\"") 
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.01
=> true
>> system("bash --login -c \"ruby -v\"") 
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.01
=> true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the full path of Ruby in app/models/deployment.rb under def deploy_in_background.

And being like this [i'm using ree]:

```
system("sh -c \"cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && /opt/ruby-enterprise/bin/ruby script/runner -e... etc.
```

Thanks to Jonathan Weiss: http://twitter.com/jweiss/status/19105123857

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your Ruby Enterprise Edition is installed in a location like /opt/ree or something similar that's outside of the default PATH?

If so, then you could try setting the path variable in your Apache configuration like so:

SetEnv PATH /usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/path/to/ree/bin

Comment: sorry! but it doesn't work for me! even no new logs in the log file!